# Why are some surfaces on my mesh that i made in blender is darker than the others?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, mesh, lighting

Why are some surfaces on my mesh is darker than the others?

image link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeXvk.jpg

I've already recalculate the normals in blender but it doesn't seem to fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Normals need to be inverted. To do that, select all Faces in Blender and then recalculate normals. You can select if the should be inside or outside in the bottom left corner of your screen.